# google ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync invalid_grant in webapi

Tags: asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0, google-signin, google-oauth, google-oauth-.net-client

i have implemented [GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow#implementing_the_one-time-code_flow) scenario from [google api client dotnet](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth#web-applications-aspnet-mvc) and  tutorial to get token from what my client sent to server as a code. but when i call `flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync` , I get the following error :

```
{"Error:\"invalid_grant\", Description:\"\", Uri:\"\""}
```

I read [google authorization invalid_grant](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/authorization#invalid_grant) and [gusclass oauth 2 using google dotnet api client libraries](https://gusclass.com/blog/2014/04/16/how-to-oauth-2-0-flows-using-the-google-net-api-client-libraries-1-7-in-c/) but they didn't help me and. I think it must be very simple but I don't know why it doesn't work.
For client side , I have used [Satellizer](https://github.com/sahat/satellizer) and this is my server Codes:

```
public bool PostExchangeAccessToken(GoogleClientAccessCode code)
        {
            string[] SCOPES = { "email" };
            IAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow(new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = new ClientSecrets()
                {
                    ClientSecret = "******",
                    ClientId = "********.apps.googleusercontent.com"
                },
                Scopes = SCOPES
            });
            try
            {
                TokenResponse token;
                token = flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("*****@gmail.com", Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(code), "https://localhost:44301/",
                                CancellationToken.None).Result;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

On [Github](https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/744#issuecomment-227995996) I found that I must use the `Token` from the client and use

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer()
```

to create my UserCredential object.

Answer (score 0):

You can check  your google developer console settings.(Authorized redirect URIs)

Credentials => OAuth 2.0 client IDs => Your Application Settings => Authorized redirect URIs

You must add url. ("https://localhost:44301/")

**My code :**

```
 flow.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync("me", authCode, redirectUri, CancellationToken.None).Result;
```

**Authorized redirect URIs**

For use with requests from a web server. This is the path in your application that users are redirected to after they have authenticated with Google. The path will be appended with the authorization code for access. Must have a protocol. Cannot contain URL fragments or relative paths. Cannot be a public IP address.